# Edit product list template

Tags: magento-1.9, template, product-list

I need add block `div` into tag `a` like on image, it is desirable programmatically.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I dont think its very clear what you are trying to do

Comment: i need add `div` block after output product image programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to resolve your problem.
1) Redeclare template `catalog/product/list.phtml`, and add your `div` block there.
2) Generate `div` block in js and add to expected place by selector.
In magento 1 theme rwd i don't know other solutions.